# How to apply transaction to a file move task?

Tags: ssis

I have a ssis package that reads file, inserts the data from the file into a db Table. Then delete the file. This is followed by a sql script.

Is there any way to apply transaction for this whole process so that suppose there is an error in the final sql script task, then the entire package gets reversed? Example: It should undo the insert data and delete file step.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No, there isn't! Transactions exist on DB level only. But anyways: you should redesign your process and put the deletion of the file at the end of your process, so a file is only deleted when all previous tasks were successful.